# pdf file is not being created using jspdf and file api in cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm trying to create and save a PDF file.
If I use

> doc.save("table.pdf");

on a PC, the PDF file is created.
However, if I add the file API, the pdf is *not* created on a mobile phone.

Code:

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
var elem = document.getElementById("myTable");
var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(elem);
doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data);

// doc.save("table.pdf");
// writer.write(doc.output());
// doc.save("table.pdf");
var pdfOutput = doc.output();
console.log( pdfOutput );
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, function(dir) {
    dir.getFile("test.pdf", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function (fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(function (writer) {
            writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
                console.log("write success");
            };     
            console.log("writing to file");
            writer.write( pdfOutput ); 
        }, 
        function ()
            console.log("ERROR SAVEFILE");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Improved formatting; tightened wording.